# Create Eigen::Ref from std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, eigen, eigen3

It is easy to copy data between e.g. `Eigen::VectorXd` and `std::vector<double>` or `std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d>`, for example

```
std::vector<Eigen::Vector3> vec1(10, {0,0,0});
Eigen::VectorXd vec2(30);
VectorXd::Map(&vec2[0], vec1.size()) = vec1;
```

(see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26094708/4069571 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/21560121/4069571)

Also, it is possible to create an `Eigen::Ref<VectorXd>` from a Matrix block/column/... for example like

```
MatrixXd mat(10,10);
Eigen::Ref<VectorXd> vec = mat.col(0);
```

**The Question**

Is it possible to create an `Eigen::Ref<VectorXd>` from a `std::vector<double>` or even `std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d>` without first copying the data?

Comment: According to the documentation it should be possible: *By default, a Ref<VectorXf> can reference any dense vector expression of float having a contiguous memory layout.* You may have to `Eigen::Map` the `std::vector<double>` first and then wrap it up as `Ref`. I always use template functions and `Ref` is intended for non-template functions. So haven't tried, but should work. Link to ref doc: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox///classEigen_1_1Ref.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried and it actually works as I describe in my comment by first mapping and then wrapping it as a `Eigen::Ref` object. Shown here through a google test.

```
void processVector(Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXd> refVec) {
  size_t size = refVec.size();
  ASSERT_TRUE(10 == size);
  std::cout << "Sum before change: " << refVec.sum(); // output is 50 = 10 * 5.0
  refVec(0) = 10.0; // for a sum of 55
  std::cout << "Sum after change: " << refVec.sum() << std::endl;
}

TEST(testEigenRef, onStdVector) {
  std::vector<double> v10(10, 5.0);
  Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> mPtr(&v10[0], 10);
  processVector(mPtr);
  // confirm that no copy is made and std::vector is changed as well
  std::cout << "Std vec[0]: " << v10[0] << std::endl; // output is 10.0
}
```

Made it a bit more elaborate after the 2nd edit. Now I have my google unit test for `Eigen::Ref` (thank you). Hope this helps.

Comment: Very clear, thanks to the unit tests, thank you.
In the end, I was copying data because I wrote `Eigen::VectorXd x = Eigen::Map<VectorXd>(...)` instead of `Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXd> x` or `Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> x`